# Selecting rows conditioned on other columns of data frame in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a data set like this

```
id <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 5)

year <- rep( c(2001 : 2005), each = 5)

status <- c(0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4 ) 

dt <- data.frame( year, id, status)
```

Notice that hare in Year 2003 for Id *B* and *D* `Status > 0` and for other years it is not. My objective is to find the observations that the Id in 2003 has status > 1 and status = 0 for all other years. If a Id do not have observations for all the year I will not consider that even though in this data all the Id's are there for all the year.

What I did is a long process and not effective-

```
id1 <- dt %>% filter(year == 2003 & status > 1)
id1 <- id1[["id"]]

dt1 <-   dt[dt$id %in% id1, ]


dt2 <- dt1 %>% filter(year != 2003) 

dt2<- dt2 %>% mutate( st2 = case_when( status == 1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ status)  )


dt2<- setDT(dt2)[, fact := +(uniqueN(st2) == 1), id]

dt2 <- dt2 %>% filter(fact == 1 ) %>% filter(st2 == 0)

id2 <- dt2[["id"]]

dt <- dt1[dt1$id %in% id2, ]

rm(id1, id2, dt1, dt2)
```

I think this gives me my desired output but not effective for repetitive work. I would really appreciate your help to find a nicer way to work on this.

***Note:*** I am new in r and programming - apologies for unorganized question.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Hi can you make sure while posting the question that your code and data are in sync and are completely reproducible? For example,  you have `Year` in your dataframe but using `year` in the code. Same for `Status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to select the Ids that meet the condition

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(Id) %>%
   filter(Status[Year == 2003]  > 1 & all(Status[Year != 2003] == 0))
```

Comment: can't figure out why I am getting this  - Error: Result must have length 10, not 2.
The code I ran is 
```
data_05 <- data_05 %>% group_by(frs_id) %>% 
      filter(v_status[year == 2005]>1 & all(v_status[year != 2005]<=1))
```

Comment: @AhadZaman Is it possible that some 'Id' doesn't have `Year` as 2003

Comment: Yes some of the "Id" do not have year as 2003 @akrun

Comment: @AhadZaman That could be reason.  If some Id do not have those, then what should be the expected for that id

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(dt)[, Status[Year == 2003] > 0 & sum(Status > 0) == 1, Id]
```

gives

```
   Id    V1
1:  A FALSE
2:  B  TRUE
3:  C FALSE
4:  D  TRUE
5:  E FALSE
```

---

If you want to filter out the desired `Id`s, you can run

```
> setDT(dt)[, .SD[Status[Year == 2003] > 0 & sum(Status > 0) == 1], Id]
    Id Year Status
 1:  B 2001      0
 2:  B 2002      0
 3:  B 2003      4
 4:  B 2004      0
 5:  B 2005      0
 6:  D 2001      0
 7:  D 2002      0
 8:  D 2003      2
 9:  D 2004      0
10:  D 2005      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am having hard time understanding ` sum(Status > 0) == 1` this in the code. Where can I get some material to read about constructing this kind of conditional statement?  Thanks @ThomaslsCoding

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to filter you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::filter(dt, (Year == 2003 & Status > 0) | (Year != 2003 & Status == 0))

 Year Id Status
1  2001  A      0
2  2001  B      0
3  2001  D      0
4  2002  A      0
5  2002  B      0
6  2002  D      0
7  2003  B      4
8  2003  C      2
9  2003  D      2
10 2003  E      1
11 2004  A      0
12 2004  B      0
13 2004  C      0
14 2004  D      0
15 2004  E      0
16 2005  A      0
17 2005  B      0
18 2005  D      0
```

If you want the distinct `Id` that meets the criteria then you can just add a pipe to `dplyr::distinct`:

```
dplyr::filter(dt, (Year == 2003 & Status > 0) | (Year != 2003 & Status == 0)) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(Id)

  Id
1  A
2  B
3  D
4  C
5  E
```